# Vue.js: How to retrieve css var under <script>

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using chartJs to add a Doughnut chart on my app, but I need to setup it's color under `<script>` and I'd like to get the color from `theme/variables.css` .

In the code below, I have a hardcoded `backgroundColor`, but I'd like to get it from `--ion-color-secondary` and `--ion-color-secondary-contrast` instead. How can I achieve that?

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <Doughnut
    :chart-data="chartData"
    :chart-options="chartOptions"
  /> 
</template>

<script lang=ts>
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'

import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs'
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ArcElement,
  CategoryScale,
  Plugin
} from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale)

export default defineComponent<{fastdata: any}>({
  name: 'MrProgress',
  components: {
    Doughnut
  },
  inject: ["fastdata"],
  setup() {
    const chartOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      cutout: "90%",
      borderWidth: 0,
    }
    return {
        chartOptions,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    chartData() {
      const pts = this.fastdata.user.pts;
      const missing = this.fastdata.user.proximo_nivel - pts;
      return {
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: ['#41B883', '#e4e0d8'],
            data: [pts, missing]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Why is it labeled with both 2 and 3 tags? For composition api, there's a convenient composable, https://vueuse.org/core/usecssvar/

Comment: I guess I labeled that way just because of my lack of experience, I through that it would apply to both versions, let me correct that. I'm using Vue 3. Thanks for the pointer regarding userCssVar, I didn't know that.

Comment: What if you change the color strings to var(--ion-color-secondary) and var(--ion-color-secondary-contrast) respectively.

Comment: @alexkarpen I get lots of compilation errors. But using `useCssVar` as pointed by @EstusFlask solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the tip from @EstusFlask in the comment regarding `userCssVar`, I manged to solve it in the following way:

`npm i @vueuse/core`

```
...
import { useCssVar } from '@vueuse/core'
import { ref } from 'vue'

<script>
...
      const color_pts = useCssVar(ref('--ion-color-secondary'), ref(null)).value;
      const color_missing = useCssVar(ref('--ion-background-color'), ref(null)).value;
      return {
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: [color_pts, color_missing],
            data: [pts, missing]
          }
        ]
      }
...
</script>
```